# Copying file to current directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

How can I copy a file and paste it into the current directory?

```
copy "C:\Users\G\file.txt"
```

And then into the cd.

Comment: your given command should do exactly what you want: copy  `"C:\Users\G\file.txt"` to the current folder. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: `copy "C:\Users\G\file.txt" .` - there is a .(dot) after the source file, . (dot) indicates the current directory.

Comment: @Rao yes, the dot refers to the current directory. But `copy` doesn't really need it. If no destination is given, it defaults to the current dir.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In CMD example:

```
C:\Users\MyUser> COPY "C:\Users\G\file.txt" file.txt
```

The file will be copied to active path:

```
C:\users\MyUser
```

Comment: if you don't give a destination, `copy` assumes the current folder as destination, Btw: single qoutes won't work.

Answer (score 5):

`C:\Users\MyUser> COPY "C:\Users\G\file.txt" .`

will copy the file `file.txt` to the current directory (in the example to `C:\Users\MyUser`).
The dot at the end denotes the current directory.